# CloudSQL proxy credentials: invalid Json file

Tags: kubernetes, cloud-sql-proxy

Am trying to use CloudSQL proxy with my container to Cloud SQL storage in GCP Kubernetes. As soon as I deploy my yaml I get the error “CrashLoopBackOff” for the pod and the “kubectl logs  cloudsql-proxy” gives me the error that the credentials.json is missing. I do have it in the home dir of my cloudtop from where I am accessing the Kubernetes cluster. I am not actually using any volumes for persistent data but should I still use the “volumes:” definition as mentioned in step 6.4 in https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-kubernetes-engine
What is the mistake am making please?

Thanks much

Comment: Follow the linked guide carefully, it is very detailed and should be easy to follow. You need to create a secret and mount it properly. Read the guide again and follow every step.